# Javascript regular expression - match */

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a tool whereby you enter incorrectly formatted CSS into one text area, hit submit and it runs a few regular expressions and feeds back the minified and "maxified" CSS in 2 other textareas. First it removes all white space (that is, unless it is within a line - only white space at the end of a line and tabs within a line is removed). It then proceeds to fall over on the next line - `reg = new RegExp("\*\/", "\g");`. The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*//: Nothing to repeat`. I can't figure out why this is. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it with `reg = /\/\*/g`; when building regexes from strings, you need to double escape everything.

Comment: Think you got it the wrong way round - it's `*/`, not `/*`. I have tried `/\*\//g` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy, if you want `*/` use `reg = /\*\//g;` and if you want `/*` use `reg = /\/\*/g;`.

Comment: Just realised the term in the title, `*/`, is correct - but the regex I stated I was trying to match it with is wrong (copied from the line below). Will correct it now.

Comment: ok got it working using `reg = /\*\//g;` and `reg = /\/\*/g;` - thanks both. @Mathletics, @DerekHenderson: if you both post your answers, I'll +1 them and mark one as the answer (will flip a coin to decide!)

Comment: Honestly you should just close the question. The regex-string-escape problem is a pretty common question, and this particular case is too localized to be useful.

Comment: The real problem is that you need to double escape "\" in strings, and the second parameter doesn't need `\`. This would work: new RegExp("\\*\\/", "g")

Comment: I agree with @Mathletics about closing the question, but I'm also happy to take the points.  ;)

Comment: @Mathletics - I'm all for closing questions which are, as you put it, too localized and common to help anyone out, but that doesn't change the fact that someone took the time to answer it and they deserve some kind of recognition for it. I'll accept Dereks answer if you aren't going to post one.

Comment: This is a job for parsing, not regex's (someone had to say it).

Comment: ok whoever downvoted this question please state WHY! It's a perfectly reasonable question, it is clear, concise and doesn't appear to be possible the way I was originally attempting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `*/` use `reg = /\*\//g;` and if you want `/*` use `reg = /\/\*/g;`.